# How to secure Spring Cloud microservices using Spring Security?

Tags: spring, security, spring-security, microservices, spring-cloud

Here is the [authorization service](https://github.com/callicoder/spring-boot-react-oauth2-social-login-demo/tree/master/spring-social). It has endpoints to login and receive a JWT using either a custom username/password or social OAuth (Facebook, GitHub etc.).

I have a Eureka server setup and Zuul gateway service. From what I understand, there are two ways to go about implementing secure microservices. You either proxy requests through the auth service, or you send requests to the requested service (Ex. Service A) and service A authorizes using the auth service.

I would like to use the second way, however I'm having trouble implementing it. Is my understanding correct? Is there a way to setup service A somehow so that certain paths (configured using Ant matchers) will have to authorize using the auth service, which will set the SecurityContext appropriately and inject a UserPrincipal into the request. If anyone can point me to a good guide for this that would be much appreciated.

Comment: I found interest links which related to your question https://www.baeldung.com/jhipster-microservices https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-openid-connect